# How to purchase physical goods using through mobile app? Payment must be made with CREDITS instead of money

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, payment-gateway, hig

In my application, I want to take an order of food, drinks, etc (For Ex. Restaurant app) and deliver or serve them. **My applications into I want to generate “CREDITS” using through payment. For Ex, 10$ = 100 credits.** Using these credits, I want to accept food orders using through CREDITS (User give payment using CREDITS instead of MONEY).

So, above scenario, As per my knowledge IN APP PURCHASE (IAP) will not be use in app because physical goods are not selling using through IAP.

Another option is Apple Pay, but it is not release universally and limited for some brand. So, this is not an issue.

So, Can I use other payment gateways like PayPal, etc? Please let us know your prior experience or comments. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use PayPal or any other online payment solution.

From my previous experience you can **only use IAP** if it's a *digital goods* that will be used within the app, and you're **not allowed to use IAP** for *physical goods* (and you can use whatever your heart desires).

Comment: Q, Thanks for your response. Here I want to generate credits instead convert to money. Credits will be manage by my own server. So, That is also not an issues. Is it right?

Comment: It shouldn't be because you're still delivering _physical goods_.

Comment: @., Thanks for your Replay. I will start work on this and let me submit my experience here.

Comment: Cool. Will be waiting for the result!

Comment: @iOS Dev, can you please explain your experience regarding above issue?